# IE8: OnChange Event does not execute JavaScript Method when clicked for the first time

Tags: internet-explorer-8

```
<s:if test="%{tool == 'leveraged'}">
<s:radio
id="extra_ID_EXERCISE_RIGHT"
name="form.ID_EXERCISE_RIGHT"
list="#{'' : ' All','2':' (alfa, beta, gama)','1':' (www, abc, def)'}"
onchange="fetchResultCountWithDelay();"/>
```

AND

```
function fetchResultCountWithDelay() {
if (delayTimer) {
    window.clearTimeout(delayTimer);
}
delayTimer = window.setTimeout("fetchResultCount()", 1300);
}
```

In IE8,  clicking on another radio button does not refresh the results.
This happens ONLY when the page is first started.

After the second click the results are refreshed.
After the first click on the radio button the results are not refreshed.

The problem is that by the first two radio buttons clicks, the fetchResultCountWithDelay() method is not executed.

Can somebody help?

Thank you !